# Run a function before a specific page load

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, helper

I need to run a function that changes a database table value **before** a specific page loads, this page would be: `mysite/index.php/mymodule/account/list/`.

```
public function updateTable(){
     $id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
     $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
     $connection->query("UPDATE my_table SET value = 0 WHERE customer_id=". "$id");

}
```

I tried to make it work calling the function in `mymodule.xml` as a helper function but it runs **after** the page loads. I also tried to call the function in my `block.phtml` file that is loaded in the account/list page with php, but it also changes the table **after** the page load.

```
<?php Mage::helper('productquestions')->updateTable() ?>
```

There's someway to make it work using `Observer.php`? If not, there is another way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible via an observer.

I'm not 100% sure how your module controller is declared, but here's the idea:

In your `config.xml` you need to add the following :

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_mymodule_account_list>
            <observers>
                <my_unique_observer_name>
                    <class>module/observer</class>
                    <method>updateTable</method>
                </my_unique_observer_name>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_mymodule_account_list>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Important note: in `controller_action_predispatch_mymodule_account_list` you'll have to replace `mymodule_account_list` with your controller details following this : `route_controller_method`

Also you'll have to replace `module/observer` with your module namespace.

Then in your observer you can do:

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer {

    public function updateTable()
    { 
         $id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
         $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
         $connection->query("UPDATE my_table SET value = 0 WHERE customer_id=". "$id");
    }

}
```

Or if you wanna keep that method in your helper you can simply do:

```
public function updateTable() 
{
    Mage::helper('productquestions')->updateTable();
}
```

Also a good thing to do is to avoid using the table name directly and use the following code to retrieve it so your code supports table prefixes:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('my_table');
```

Comment: nicely done, but you might want to add the table prefix in case the table was generated via a proper install script.

Comment: @Marius 100% correct, I just copied/pasted the OP code ^^

Answer (score 0):

in this `controller_action_predispatch` event you can do your logic

in this event check your handler and if you found your handler then run that helper function